# sql test condition if failed move to next person

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the urns that don't have a status_mvf  = 88

```
status_mvf    urn        desc        date
88            104        no show     2017-03-06
9             104        late        2017-03-07
2             104        on time     2017-03-08
2             210        on time     2017-03-06
2             210        on time     2017-03-07
9             320        late        2017-03-06

SELECT   
    a.Status_Mvf,
    p.URN,
    v.ADMIT_DATE


FROM APPOINTMENT  
WHERE  Status_Mvf <> '88'

--group by p.urn,

ORDER BY URN, STATUS_MVF
```

Desired result - no urn 104 because it had an 88

```
status_mvf   urn       desc      date
2            210       on time   2017-03-06
2            210       on time   2017-03-07
9            320       late      2017-03-06
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here, or what the problem is... Please edit the post to clarify.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Please paste the actual query - you're referring to a.Status and p.URN which suggests you aren't showing us the full query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from appointment a
where not exists (select 1 from appointment a2 where a2.urn = a.urn and a2.status_mvf = '88');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (with a NOT IN statement):

```
SELECT a.Status_Mvf, p.URN, v.ADMIT_DATE
FROM APPOINTMENT a
WHERE urn NOT IN
 (
    SELECT a2.urn FROM APPOINTMENT a2
    WHERE a2.Status_Mvf = '88'
 )         
ORDER BY URN, STATUS_MVF
```

Comment: much cleaner and easier.  I went with this.  Thanks